# Django migrations workflow

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have 3 migrations already thats in production

Migration-1
Migration-2
Migration-3

Now, Im adding some dev work and constantly trying out different things
and end up with 5 additional migrations.

Migration-1
Migration-2
Migration-3
Migration-4
Migration-5
Migration-6
Migration-7
Migration-8

Question:-
When I take and apply the migration will Django migrations will automatically start from migration-4 until migration-8?

Im trying to understand the workflow but could not find a good document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact django save the applied datamigration scripts in a table in your database called `django_migrations`, so he can track which one is applied and start from the next. So if a script is already applied, he will not be applied again until you delete it from the database.

```
python manage.py showmigrations --list
```

This will list all apps in the project and the migrations associated with each app. Also it will but a big X next to the migrations that have already been applied.

To understand more about the django migrations in depth I will recommend this [good article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-migrations-a-primer/)